# Create new variable based on two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dateset about the number of School_children attending specific online courses, monitored on a quarterly basis. We would want to know the +/- movements of schoolkid numbers of the courses from one Quarter to the next one for each course.

Therefore, I like a solution in my select statement to create a new variable called `Switch` has values:

1. `yes_plus` value is when if there was a positive change of School_children (numbers) within a specific online_course between consecutive dates (Quarter_dates).
2. `yes_neg` value is when if there was a negative change of School_children (numbers) within a specific online_course between consecutive dates (Quarter_dates).
3. `no` value is when if there was no change of School_children (numbers) within a specific online_course between consecutive dates (Quarter_dates).

If no statement can be made as there is no previous data, the field should remain blank or NULL.

I Have:

```sql
+------------+-----------------+---------------+
|    date    | School_children | online_course |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+
| 30/06/2019 |            1109 | C1284         |
| 30/09/2019 |            1129 | C1284         |
| 30/12/2019 |            1158 | C1284         |
| 30/03/2020 |            1110 | C1284         |
| 30/06/2020 |            1229 | C1284         |
| 30/06/2019 |           13822 | C1285         |
| 30/09/2019 |           13822 | C1285         |
| 30/12/2019 |           13822 | C1285         |
| 30/03/2020 |           13822 | C1285         |
| 30/06/2020 |           13822 | C1285         |
| 30/06/2019 |            2163 | C1286         |
| 30/09/2019 |            2466 | C1286         |
| 30/12/2019 |            3018 | C1286         |
| 30/03/2020 |            3712 | C1286         |
| 30/06/2020 |            4413 | C1286         |
| 30/06/2019 |            4418 | C1287         |
| 30/09/2019 |            4511 | C1287         |
| 30/12/2019 |            4663 | C1287         |
| 30/03/2020 |            4922 | C1287         |
| 30/06/2020 |            5167 | C1287         |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

I want:

```sql
+------------+-----------------+---------------+----------+
|    date    | School_children | online_course |  Switch  |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+----------+
| 30/06/2019 |            1109 | C1284         | null     |
| 30/09/2019 |            1129 | C1284         | yes_plus |
| 30/12/2019 |            1158 | C1284         | yes_plus |
| 30/03/2020 |            1110 | C1284         | yes_neg  |
| 30/06/2020 |            1229 | C1284         | yes_plus |
| 30/06/2019 |           13822 | C1285         | null     |
| 30/09/2019 |           13822 | C1285         | no       |
| 30/12/2019 |           13822 | C1285         | no       |
| 30/03/2020 |           13822 | C1285         | no       |
| 30/06/2020 |           13822 | C1285         | no       |
| 30/06/2019 |            2163 | C1286         | null     |
| 30/09/2019 |            2466 | C1286         | yes_plus |
| 30/12/2019 |            3018 | C1286         | yes_plus |
| 30/03/2020 |            3712 | C1286         | yes_plus |
| 30/06/2020 |            4413 | C1286         | yes_plus |
| 30/06/2019 |            4418 | C1287         | null     |
| 30/09/2019 |            4511 | C1287         | yes_plus |
| 30/12/2019 |            4663 | C1287         | yes_plus |
| 30/03/2020 |            4922 | C1287         | yes_plus |
| 30/06/2020 |            5167 | C1287         | yes_plus |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+----------+
```

How can this be archived within a select statement?

Comment: Please don't use images, formatted text is much neater and possible to copy and paste. Also show us you attempt to date.

Comment: So the first attempt was to create a rank as in:

Comment: [edit] it directly into your question

Comment: So the first attempt was to create a rank as in:                                                
  SELECT 
  *
 ,RANK() OVER (
    PARTITION BY [online_course]  
    ORDER BY [Date] asc
) AS RANKS 
INTO #TEST1
FROM #TEST   That way, I already know that all RANKS=1 will be NULL

Comment: and then I would need something along the lines:                                           
  SELECT * 
, CASE 
WHEN RANKS 1 THEN SWITCH = 'NULL'
WHEN RANKS =2 AND School_children (larger than School_children in RANKS 1) THEN SWITCH = 'YES_PLUS' 
WHEN RANKS =3 AND School_children (larger than School_children in RANKS 2) THEN SWITCH = 'YES_PLUS' 
WHEN RANKS =4 AND School_children (larger than School_children in RANKS 3) THEN SWITCH = 'YES_PLUS' ect
ELSE SWITCH = 'YES_NEG' END;
FROM #TEST1   But not sure how to write this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this.  It compares the LAG(school_children) to school_children within  online_course partitions.

```
drop table if exists dbo.test_table;
go
create table dbo.test_table(
  [Date]                    date not null,
  school_children           int not null,
  online_course             varchar(100) not null);

insert dbo.test_table([Date], school_children, online_course) values
('2016-10-17',1458, 'A1'),
('2016-10-18',1458, 'A1'),
('2016-10-19',10468, 'A1'),
('2016-10-20',2478, 'A1');

select
  *,
  school_children-lag(school_children) over (partition by online_course order by [Date]) school_chldrn_diff,
  iif(school_children=lag(school_children) over (partition by online_course order by [Date]), 'no',
      iif(school_children>lag(school_children) over (partition by online_course order by [Date]), 'yes_plus',
      iif(school_children<lag(school_children) over (partition by online_course order by [Date]), 'yes_neg', null))) Switch
from
  dbo.test_table;
```

Results

```
Date        school_children online_course   school_chldrn_diff  Switch
2016-10-17  1458            A1              NULL                NULL
2016-10-18  1458            A1              0                   no
2016-10-19  10468           A1              9010                yes_plus
2016-10-20  2478            A1              -7990               yes_neg
```

Comment: From that calculation, can you also add a column with the actual numerical difference in School_children  from quarter to quarter?

Comment: For those who wanted to know the answer to the second question as well: https://learnsql.com/blog/difference-between-two-rows-in-sql/

Comment: Hi @Anna.  Yep, it's just like it says in that article.  I've updated the answer here as well.